# How to "compress" similar branches in F# pattern matching

Tags: f#

I have the following piece of code in hand:

```
    match intersection with
    | None ->
        printfn "Please provide an empty intersection for ring placement"
        gameState
    | Some x ->
        match x.Status with
        | Empty ->
            let piece = { Color = gameState.Active.Color; Type = Ring }
            putPieceOnIntersection gameState.Board pos piece

            printfn "%s ring placed at %A" (colorStr gameState.Active.Color) pos

            // Decide if we ended this phase
            let updatedPhase = if ringsPlaced = 10 then Main else Start(ringsPlaced + 1)
            let newActivePlayer = gameState.Players |> Array.find (fun p -> p.Color = invertColor gameState.Active.Color)
            let updatedGameState = { gameState with Active = newActivePlayer; CurrentPhase = updatedPhase }

            updatedGameState
        | _ ->
            printfn "Please provide an empty intersection for ring placement"
            gameState
```

As you may see, if the variable *intersection* is either None or its Status is different than empty, I should do exactly the same branch of printing some text and return. However I don't know how to do that kind of condition expression in F# so that I can share the same branch. In imperative programming I would do this easily, but in F# how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: What is the type of `x` in `Some x`?

Comment: It is a type called "Intersection" which contains a member called Status and a Position. Here's the definition, although I didn't think that was relevant:

    type Intersection = {
        mutable Status: Status;
        Position: Position
        }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `Status` is a record field then you can do:

```
match intersection with
| Some { Status = Empty } ->
    // Code for empty...
| _ ->
    printfn "Please provide an empty intersection for ring placement"
    gameState
```

Otherwise, you can use a guard:

```
match intersection with
| Some x when x.Status = Empty ->
    // Code for empty...
| _ ->
    printfn "Please provide an empty intersection for ring placement"
    gameState
```

Comment: In your first code example, what if I needed the content inside the "Some" (x in my case)?

Comment: You can do `Some ({ Status = Empty } as x)`

Comment: Wow, that is the syntax I really needed! Thank you!